# Mantener 2 decimales en un double en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando una suma de tres números tipo `double`.

Para ello dos de los valores a sumar tienen dos dígitos decimales.

Pero el último valor solo cuenta con un valor decimal, y al hacer la suma de éste me arroja muchos decimales en el resultado de mi suma y lo entiendo es por la precisión del tipo de dato `double`.

Es un dato dinámico, así que como tal a veces llega un decimal y en otros llegan los dos decimales, quiero conservar solo los dos decimales sin redondear.

Supongamos que los siguientes números son dinámicos:

```
double num1 = 222.22;
double num2 = 345.10;
double num3 = 122.2;

double result = num1 + num2 + num3;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

El resultado que espero es `689.52`, pero el resultado que obtengo realmente es `689.5200000000001`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La respuesta rápida es que **no puedes mantener el número de decimales que desees** en un valor de tipo `double` de manera automatizada sin usar métodos que realicen redondeo.

Tal y como has intuido, esto es debido a la precisión del dato `double` y forma recomendada de solucionarlo sin alterar el contenido de la variable con métodos de redondeo es usar un formato adecuado a la hora de mostrar el contenido de esa variable.

Por ejemplo:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", result));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.##}", result));
```

En el primer caso los valores decimales se rellenan con `0` hasta el número de decimales deseado usando redondeo, pero en el segundo caso no se realiza ese relleno, solo el redondeo.

Mi recomendación es mantener siempre el valor "nativo" de la variable (para no perder más precisión por culpa de redondeos) y solo cambiar el formato al mostrar su contenido.

Answer (score 3):

Tal como señalas el problema es por la precisión del tipo double, para conservar los 2 decimales **sin aproximar**, puedes:

1. Representación en string - Si este dato solo lo necesitas para presentación (no para realizar otros cálculos)

```
double num1 = 222.22;
double num2 = 345.10;
double num3 = 122.2;
double result = num1 + num2 + num3;
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("#.00")); //689,52
```

2. Si vas a realizar más calculo con el dato, yo pienso que lo mejor es convertir todo a decimal

```
decimal num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(222.22);
decimal num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(345.10);
decimal num3 = Convert.ToDecimal(122.2);
decimal result = num1 + num2 + num3;
Console.WriteLine(result); //689,52
```

3. Siempre puedes usar Math.truncate, que te da la parte entera, entonces hay que multiplicar y dividir

```
double num1 = 222.22;
double num2 = 345.10;
double num3 = 122.2;
double result = num1 + num2 + num3;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Truncate(100 * result) / 100); //689,52
```

---

Como nota aparte este problema trasciende a c#, puede verse en una multitud de lenguajes como javascript

```js
console.log(222.22+345.10+122.2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece raro que te de ese resultado, ¿qué versión de C# estás utilizando?

Por otro lado, coloca el siguiente código en https://dotnetfiddle.net/

En los comentarios tiene el resultado generado.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        double num1 = 222.22;
        double num2 = 345.10;
        double num3 = 122.2;
        double result = num1 + num2 + num3;
        Console.WriteLine(result); // 689.52
        var resultRounded = Math.Round(result, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(resultRounded); // 689.52
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el numero es de tipo moneda por ejemplo el precio de varios objetos de un carrito de la compra puedes utilizar el tipo *decimal*

```
decimal num1 = 222.22M;
decimal num2 = 345.10M;
decimal num3 = 122.2M;

decimal result = num1 + num2 + num3;
Console.WriteLine($"{result}");
```

1. Output

689.52

El tipo de decimal se usa para cálculos monetarios sin errores de redondeo. **Cuidado** no se elimina la necesidad de redondeo.

Comment: No cuadran mucho en la misma frase las palabras "sin errores de redondeo" y "no se elimina la necesidad de redondeo". Los errores de redondeo existirán siempre que se usen tipos de datos de coma flotante, ya sea de tipo `float`, `double` o `decimal`. Solo cambian la precisión entre sí (32, 64 o 128 bits, con 6-9, 15-17 y 28-29 dígitos respectivamente) y no el problema subyacente de hacer uso de aritmética de coma flotante. [Más información](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types).

Comment: Sin error de redondeo en los cálculos monetarios ,no es en la misma frase.

Comment: Para mas información te remito a la documentación oficial:https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.8#code-try-10

Comment: Precisamente es un error que tiene la documentación oficial de Microsoft. No puede recomendarte el tipo `decimal` como una alternativa para no cometer errores de redondeo y, acto seguido, indicar que sigue teniendo la necesidad de efectuar redondeo e incluso ponerte un trozo de código en el que se muestra el problema del redondeo.

Comment: Esto me recuerda a una película de Superman la 2 o la 3 que uno se hace rico robando los redondeos de las nominas de una empresa.